# storing data in bytecode in RDBMS

Tags: database-design, rdbms

I have the following DDL

```
create table repeat_group(
    id int,
    start_date date.
    end_date date, 
    createby int,
    createdon timestamp not null default current_timestamp,
    updatedby int,
    updatedon timestamp,
    primary key(id)
);
```

The table represents a group of classes which are to be repeated for weekdays between start_date and end_date. I want to store the days on which a group will be repeated in a column in this table.

I came up with three solutions:

1. Make 7 columns for each weekday and store a flag naming it as `recurring_day`. This will create a lot of NULLs.
2. Make a separate table and relate it as one to many relationship.
3. Store the days in some code (For ex: bytecode) like so:
   column name : `recussing_days char(7)`. This will store a 7 character string like `0000010`. This code means that the class will be repeated on every saturday between `start_date` and `end_date`.

I want to ask which solution is the most efficient, considering the 3rd solution will require computation. Also, if there is any other efficient solution.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It depends what you mean by "efficient", and how your data will be used.

If you're aiming for readability, I would have one column for each day of the week. A developer who is trying to work out whether a course is run on Mondays just has to look at the column "Monday"; all the queries will be very descriptive and easy to understand. However, the fact your day columns will have sparse data with low cardinality means they won't be index-friendly; if you're storing millions of rows, this *may* be a problem.

If you're aiming for absolute speed, I'd use an integer to store the days, and use bitwise arithmetic; most RDBMS engines are really good at this, and the integer field may be more "index-friendly" because you are likely to have a decent spread of values. However, the queries are less legible, and you may end up with silly bugs (does the week start on Sunday or Monday?).

This is very fast, because each combination of dates equates to a different, unique integer, which in turn allows the column to be efficiently indexed. The initial calculation (turn "Monday and Tuesday not Wednesday and (Thursday or Friday) into a integer") happens only once, and is very fast. However, comparing that integer to the millions of records in your "classes" table (I got "millions from your comment, but that seems a very large number...) is the time consuming bit.

I certainly wouldn't store your bit flag in a string - that way you lose the benefit of the built-in bitwise logic.

The separate table may be easy to read, but could lead to awkward queries - find all courses that run on Mondays and Tuesdays, but not on Wednesdays requires several joins/in clauses. This may be harder to glue into a front-end (especially if you're using an ORM).

Comment: There will be millions of rows since there are so many classes everyday. So the bit wise logic is the solution. But instead of storing and int(7), as in 7 places representing each day, can I do it in less digits? Like applying an algorithm, anything like this already implemented? Also, storing or retrieving would require computation. Will that be too much of an overhead? Like the UI selects the names of the days and they’re stored as integers.

Comment: What I am looking for is by performance point of view. By efficient I mean storage and retrieval should be fast. So which will be the fastest.

Comment: What are you hoping to achieve with an "algorithm to use fewer places"? A bitmap translates directly to an integer, the logic is super clear, and it performs very well in searching. The logic to translate days of the week to a bitmap is not complex or slow...